# Reverse engineering Entity Relationship Diagram

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, entity-relationship

I wanted to know if any tools exist that help in reverse-engineering the Entity Relationship Diagram from an existing Firestore Database. I have already made my database on Cloud Firestore and now I wanted to have a look at my entity-relationship diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only tool I know that generates entity relationship diagrams for Firestore is [Hackolade](https://hackolade.com/) but the reverse-engineering feature is under development at the moment.

> Reverse-Engineering
>
> Note: the reverse-engineering of documents is not
> currently available.  It is being developed and will be released at a
> later time
>
> https://hackolade.com/help/Firestore.html

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that but can't use it currently right. So no point.